# Running multiple instances of same python script on Linux server

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have this script that simulates visits to a website where each visit is counted using different user-agents. Let's say I want to run this script 50 times simultaneously, passing different user-agents as parameter to each script.

```
u = ['user-agent0', 'user-agent49']

def function(user_agent):
    pass # My function

# Passing each element from my user-agent list
for i in range(50):
    function(u[i])
```

In this for loop the script will run 50 times but one after another. How can I pass each different user-agent and run all of them simultaneously?

Comment: Put 50 things in `u`, then do `for agent in u:` / `function(agent)`.

Comment: You can use the `multiprocessing` module to run 50 processes simultaneously.  If these are I/O-bound tasks, like making a web request, you may be able to get by with threading.

Comment: There are so many possible ways to do this, and so little information in the question to narrow down which is best, I have trouble seeing this question as narrow enough to be on topic. A question asking about a specific problem encountered while implementing a specific approach would be far more amenable to a canonical answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "each visit is counted using different user-agents?" Are you actually maintaining a count of something and if so, what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the given answers and a couple more of research I think I've come up with a solution, still not sure if it's the best but it works fine.
I used the `Process` class from the `multiprocesssing` module to create multiple processes using a single function from my code. Here's an example:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

list = ["Honda", "Toyota", "Ford"]

def cars(brand):
    print("Car:", brand)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    procs = []
    p1 = Process(target=cars, args=(list[0],))
    p1.start()
    procs.append(p1)

    p2 = Process(target=cars, args=(list[1],))
    p2.start()
    procs.append(p2)
    
    p3 = Process(target=cars, args=(list[2],))
    p3.start()
    procs.append(p3)

    for p in procs:
        p.join()
```

I did this same code with Selenium and it works just as expected: opens 3 web browsers at the same time. Hope this can help anyone. Thanks for everybody who answered the question!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a primitive example:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

u = ['user-agent0', ... 'user-agent49']

def function(user_agent):
    return 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(len(u)) as p:
        p.map(function, u)
```

Lots of variations are possible.  Note that "run at the same time" only goes so far.  You will be limited by bandwidth, and the response time of your web server.  You may want to limit the size of the pool to run 10 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use something like this too, but it is must do some adjust to your code. This way, you can run parallel jobs using a bash shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash
array=( "user-agent0" "user-agent49" )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    python your_new_script.py $i &
done

wait 
echo "All done completed"
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but you could use a bash script to run multiple python files at once. Make a .txt file with all your user agents.

Create 50 copies of your script in the current directory. (replace `my_script` with your script name). You may need to change 50 to 49, I'm still new to bash.

`$ for i in {0..50}; do cp my_script.py my_script$i.py; done`

In your python file, use argparse to take command line arguments (you would add this in place of your user agents list)

```py
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Substitute user agent")
parser.add_argument("user_agent")
args = parser.parse_args()
user_agent = args[1]
```

Create bash script to run all 50 files at once, using your list of user agents as command line arguments for each instance.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
user_agent_list=()
while read line
do
    user_agent_list+=( "$line" )
done < user_agents.txt
wait
script_list=()
for py_script in $(find . -name 'my_script*.py')
do
    script_list+=( "$py_script" )
done
wait
list_len=${#script_list}
for i in {0..list_len}
do
    python3 ${script_list[i]} --user_agent ${user_agent_list[i]} &
done
```

Something like that would run all 50 scripts at once, each with a unique user agent pulled from an external text file.

If someone sees something wrong with this let me know, I'm still learning and am always looking for pointers.

Comment: `for i in {0..${#script_list}}` doesn't work in bash, because parameter expansion happens **after** brace expansion. See [BashPitfalls #33](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D).

Comment: Also, `user_agent_list += line` isn't valid assignment syntax. It's quite clear this code has never been tested. (The correct syntax would be `user_agent_list+=( "$line" )` -- note in particular the whitespace changes).

Comment: Also, `script_list = ()` is wrong too -- can't have spaces around the `=`.